# Copying formula linking another worksheet in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to copy this formula **Posts_HC!$H$22** down a column but want the H to change to I  then to J... etc.in subsequent cells

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Change it to **Posts_HC!H$22**.

The dollar sign allows you to *fix* either the row, the column or both on any cell reference.

In this case you have to remove it from columns.